# How to update pins in xamarin forms maps?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation, xamarin.forms.maps

I have the following code:

```
private async void setHelpersPins(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var temp = await firebaseHelper.GetAllHelperUsers();

    if (map.Pins.Count>0)
    {
        map.Pins.Clear();
    }

    foreach (var user in temp)
    {
        Pin pin = new Pin
        {
            Label = user.Nickname,
            Address = "További információkért kattints ide.",
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(user.Latitude, user.Longitude)
        };                
        map.Pins.Add(pin);
    }
}
```

It runs every 10second by using `Timer.Elapsed`.

But it makes the map blinks every time this method runs, which is not great for me.

How can I only update those pin coordinates, where the user's nicknames are the same?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?  Do you know how to find the existing pins that match a search criteria?  Do you know how to make an update to an existing pin?

Comment: I dont know any of them, but I wanna know both, if you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find the elements of a collection, use a LINQ query

```
using System.Linq;

....

var pins = map.Pins.Where(x => x.Label == "somevalue").ToList();
```

then you can iterate over the list to update it

```
foreach (var p in pins)
{
  p.Position = someNewPosition;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! 
How can I bind the new (p) list to the map.Pins?